# Confusing global constant variable in rust

Tags: variables, rust, global-variables

I did many experiment with rust global variables i can't understand;
why is this happening

```
#![allow(unused)]

const I:i32 = 10;

fn main() {
    let gi = I;
    println!("{}", gi);
    const I:i32 = 20;
    println!("{}", gi);
}
```

when i do this i expect this output

```
10
10
```

but the output i get is this

```
20
20
```

I have not touched `gi` but it still changes when i change global variable `I`
also if i change `I` after printing `gi` once i do not understand why the first output also changes that breaks the flow of control

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a matter of reassigning something supposed to be const, but rather a matter of shadowing a constant with another with the same name.

Your first constant has a global scope but your second one exists in the scope of the `main()` function.
In this function, if we refer to `I` it will be found in the smaller enclosing scope, which is the `main()` function.

In the modified example below, I introduce a new block in order to illustrate this.
From the point of view of `gi`, `I` is found at the global scope, but once inside the artificial block `I` refers to its second definition (in this block).

The confusing part is that the inner constant is found even if it is defined after the statement referring to it.
If it was a variable, it would not be correct, but because it is a constant, the order is not important (this is like a lexical substitution).
It would be the same situation if the top `I` appeared below the `main()` function: it would exist in the global scope anyway.

```rust
const I: i32 = 10;

fn main() {
    let gi = I;
    println!("before block: gi={}  I={}", gi, I);
    {
        println!("enter block: gi={}  I={}", gi, I);
        const I: i32 = 20;
        println!("leave block: gi={}  I={}", gi, I);
    }
    println!("after block: gi={}  I={}", gi, I);
}
/*
before block: gi=10  I=10
enter block: gi=10  I=20
leave block: gi=10  I=20
after block: gi=10  I=10
*/
```

Comment: Order is not important not just for constants, but for any item (struct, enum, type alias, fn, trait, ...), defined inside a function or outside it.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful that `I` is not a global variable, but a constant, which is not the same. A constant cannot be updated, as they are evaluated at compile time.

In addition, Rust has lexical rules with regard to shadowing. A local name will always override a less local one.
The fact that you have used `#![allow(unused)]` here makes me think that you might have seen the following warning, didn't pay attention it and chose to ignore it:

```
warning: constant `I` is never used
 --> src/main.rs:1:7
  |
1 | const I:i32 = 10;
  |       ^
  |
```

It is fairly explicit though in pointing out that you never actually used the outer `I` in your code, but the inner one.

Finally, for constants and functions, the order of declarations does not matter, so declaring a constant in the middle of your function body is the same as declaring it at the top.

As a result of the previous explanation, it can be inferred that your example is equivalent to:

```
const Outer_I:i32 = 10;

fn main() {
    const Local_I:i32 = 20;        

    let gi = Local_I;
    println!("{}", gi);
    println!("{}", gi);
}
```